# login time attribute in eDirectory

Tags: ldap, novell

I cannot find an attribute in our eDirectory schema that provides a record of a user's last login time, as in what is the date and time of their last login, not how long were they logged in for (don't have that later attribute either but I don't need that one).

SUSE SLES 10, OES 2, eDirectory 8.8.

Is it normal to not have the attribute? How do I get this functionality?

Comment: That's usually something I would expect and want in log files, not an LDAP directory.

Comment: Do not confuse loginTime with lastLoginTime.  The current last login time, is loginTime.  The one before that should be in lastLoginTime which is lightly confusing naming choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go... I feel your pain, I once had the same issue

You can use ldapsearch eg:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -x -h 172.16.0.223 -Z -D cn=admin,o=local -W  "(&(objectclass=Person))" logintime
```

If you want a nice clean csv file pipe it through this...

```
| sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/ou=OFFICE1,o=local\n//g'  | sed 's/dn: cn=//' | sed 's/logintime: //g' | sed 's/Z$//g' | grep -v "^$" > user.login.times.csv
```

Extra options... Heres a search I did to get only a list of people whom hadnt logged in before a specific date

```
ldapsearch -LLL -x -h 172.16.0.223 -Z -D cn=admin,o=local -W "(&(objectclass=Person)(loginTime<=20110101000000Z))" logintime > users.logintime.before.jan.1.2011.txt
```

If you are partial to windows tools, you can use [nlist](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/qna/7052.html)